# Element wise multiplication of matrices of differing dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix

In Matlab, I need to multiply element wise two matrices of M x N and M x kN dimensions. In other words they are of the same height, but the second matrix is k times wider, so each element in matrix A must be multiplied by k elements of the row in matrix B.

It's a bit tricky to explain, I'm sorry if it's not clear. Obviously I'm aware of .* but I can't figure out how to get this working.

```
A = [2 3;...
    4 5]
B = [9 8 7 6;...
    8 7 6 5]
```

I need to multiply |2*9, 2*8, 3*7, 3*6| 4*8, 4*7, 5*6, 5*5| to get the result

```
C = [18 16 21 18;...
    32 28 30 25]
```

Can this be done efficiently without resorting to a cumbersome for loop? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, Which seems to be what you want and provides the same results as what you post.

```
A = [2 3;
     4 5];
B = [9 8 7 6;
     8 7 6 5];
A = imresize(A,size(B),'nearest');
C = A.*B
```

This will only really work in the particular case you are presenting though. It also assumes you have the image processing toolbox

Comment: nice use of `imresize` ;)

Comment: Doesn't pretty much every distro of MATLAB contain image processing though

Comment: I guess just every one I have used has it. My bad

Answer (score 1):

You can permute, reshape, multiply element-wise, permute again and reshape back:

```
X = bsxfun(@times, A, reshape(B.', size(A,1), size(A,2), []));  %'// elementwise
C = reshape(permute(X, [1 3 2]), size(B));
```